# What's best to use in managing time between php pages - Session or Database

Tags: php, database, session

I have a simple question management portal to prepare students for an upcoming exam. In this software, a time is allocated for each student per test.

Here is the process I have at hand.

Student login, the page get like 80 unique ID which will be the question the student will answer, the page also get the time start and the first question loads on something like quest1.php then when the student click Next, the page saves the current time inside database. It pulls the saved time from the database and on and on like that.

Now when several people are using the portal, is it possible the mysql database got tired and may stop responding.

So the question is, is it good to save time inside Session instead of database.

Comment: _is it possible the mysql database got tired and may stop responding_ LOL I have heard that the database likes a Tea break every hour, to stop it getting tired

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'd literally just started typing almost the exact same comment...

Comment: He might mean red locks due to multiple user access, you should structure and plan your database hierarchy as much as your software - don't hold and store data over long period time intivals, use table cross referencing and attributes

Comment: Actually, I have tried the web app on a local server and shared it with about 300 systems at once. But while the student are attempting the test, somtimes the time just sieze which I believe that the mysql database fails to supply data due to several request at once.

Comment: @riggsfolly check the comment I put above. I need to deploy this web app online and I don't want users to have issues with the time.